# CSS Borders Started Cutting Boxes In Half

Tags: css, border-radius

Sometime last week all boxes with CSS borders (I'm just presuming here, as turning off the CSS border options in style sheets "fixes" the problem) started displaying this "glass" like behavior and trying to cut themselves in half. What's caused this and how can I fix it permanently?

[The boxes as they display with the border radius option enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMD0n.png)
[The boxes as they display once the border radius options is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykQJ6.png)

So far I've tried disabling the CSS, and while this works I don't think I can do this on every page. Unless there's some script to enforce it. I want to know what has changed which is causing this behavior.

Comment: Unless you can demonstrate the issue with a code sample, you're wasting your time posting here.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.